# Why won't my AJAX function correctly populate a drop-down list in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

I am writing a page with PHP, and I am trying to populate a drop-down list given the value of a previous drop-down list. This works perfectly in Firefox, but does not work at all in Internet Explorer. I was wondering if it is a fluke that it works in Firefox and not IE, or if I am just WAY off in the way I am doing this. Here is what I have:

Main Page:

```
<select id="make" name="make" onChange="carCompanyListHandler(this.value);">
    <option selected disabled>Choose Make</option>
    <optgroup label="American Cars">
            <option value="chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
            <option value="dodge">Dodge</option>
            <option value="ford">Ford</option>
            <option value="jeep">Jeep</option>
            <option value="tesla">Tesla</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="UK Car Companies">
            <option value="astonmartin">Aston Martin</option>
            <option value="bentley">Bentley</option>
            <option value="landrover">Land Rover</option>
            <option value="lotus">Lotus</option>
            <option value="morgan">Morgan</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Japanese Cars">
            <option value="acura">Acura</option>
            <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
            <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
            <option value="subaru">Subaru</option>
            <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Italian Cars">
            <option value="alfaromeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
            <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
            <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
            <option value="lamborghini">Lamborghini</option>
            <option value="maserati">Maserati</option>
    </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="German Cars">
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
            <option value="goliath">Goliath</option>
            <option value="porche">Porche</option>
            <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function carCompanyListHandler(carCompany){
    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();

    if (xmlHttp == null){
            alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
            return;
    }

    var url = "./ajaxprocessor.php?carCompany=" + carCompany;
    url = url + "&sid=" + Math.random();
    console.log(url);

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = populateModels;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function populateModels(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete"){
            var selectList = document.getElementById('model');
            var selectListOptions = xmlHttp.responseText;
            console.log(selectListOptions);
            selectList.innerHTML = selectListOptions;
            return;
    }
}
```

The Back-End PHP:

```
<?php
    $carCompany = (isset($_GET['carCompany']) && $_GET['carCompany'] != "") ? $_GET['carCompany'] : null;
    $returnValue = null;

    error_log("The car company chosen was: " . $carCompany);

    switch($carCompany){
            case "chevrolet":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"camaro\">Camaro</option>\n<option value=\"corvette\">Corvette</option>\n<option value=\"lumina\">Lumina</option>\n<option value=\"silverado\">Silverado</option>\n<option value=\"volt\">Volt</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "dodge":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"avenger\">Avenger</option>\n<option value=\"challenger\">Challenger</option>\n<option value=\"charger\">Charger</option>\n<option value=\"dakota\">Dakota</option>\n<option value=\"ramcharger\">Ramcharger</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "ford":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"fiesta\">Fiesta</option>\n<option value=\"focus\">Focus</option>\n<option value=\"taurus\">Taurus</option>\n<option value=\"explorer\">Explorer</option>\n<option value=\"f150\">F-150</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "jeep":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"compass\">Compass</option>\n<option value=\"cherokee\">Cherokee</option>\n<option value=\"patriot\">Patriot</option>\n<option value=\"wrangler\">Wrangler</option>\n<option value=\"srt8\">SRT8</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "tesla":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"teslaroadster\">Tesla Roadster</option>\n<option value=\"models\">Model S</option>\n<option value=\"modelx\">Model X</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "astonmartin":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"v8vantage\">V8 Vantage</option>\n<option value=\"db9volante\">DB9 Volante</option>\n<option value=\"rapide\">Rapide</option>\n<option value=\"astonmartinv12zagato\">Aston Martin V12 Zagato</option>\n<option value=\"cygnet\">Cygnet</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "bentley":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"mulsanne\">Mulsanne</option>\n<option value=\"flyingspur\">Flying Spur</option>\n<option value=\"continentalgt\">Continental GT</option>\n<option value=\"continentalgtc\">Continental GTC</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "landrover":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"defender\">Defender</option>\n<option value=\"freelander\">Freelander</option>\n<option value=\"discovery\">Discovery</option>\n<option value=\"rangerover\">Range Rover</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "lotus":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"elise\">Elise</option>\n<option value=\"exige\">Exige</option>\n<option value=\"evora\">Evora</option>\n<option value=\"2eleven\">2-Eleven</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "morgan":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"evagt\">Eva GT</option>\n<option value=\"pluse\">Plus E</option>\n<option value=\"anniversdary4x4\">Anniversdary 4x4</option>\n<option value=\"aeroplus\">Aero Plus</option>\n<option value=\"roadster\">Roadster</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "acura":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"ilx\">ILX</option>\n<option value=\"MDX\">MDX</option>\n<option value=\"rdx\">RDX</option>\n<option value=\"tsx\">TSX</option>\n<option value=\"zdx\">ZDX</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "mazda":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"mazda2\">Mazda 2</option>\n<option value=\"mazda3\">Mazda 3</option>\n<option value=\"mazda6\">Mazda 6</option>\n<option value=\"mx5\">MX-5</option>\n<option value=\"cx5\">CX-5</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "nissan":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"leaf\">Leaf</option>\n<option value=\"sentra\">Sentra</option>\n<option value=\"altima\">Altima</option>\n<option value=\"cube\">Cube</option>\n<option value=\"titan\">Titan</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "subaru":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"brz\">BRZ</option>\n<option value=\"exiga\">Exiga</option>\n<option value=\"forester\">Forester</option>\n<option value=\"outback\">Outback</option>\n<option value=\"stella\">Stella</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "toyota":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"corolla\">Corolla</option>\n<option value=\"camry\">Camry</option>\n<option value=\"tacoma\">Tacoma</option>\n<option value=\"tundra\">Tundra</option>\n<option value=\"4runner\">4Runner</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "alfaromeo":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"4c\">4C</option>\n<option value=\"mito\">Mito</option>\n<option value=\"giulietta\">Giulietta</option>\n<option value=\"159\">159</option>\n<option value=\"quadrifoglio\">Quadrifoglio</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "ferrari":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"california\">California</option>\n<option value=\"458italia\">458 Italia</option>\n<option value=\"458spider\">458 Spider</option>\n<option value=\"f12berlinetta\">F12 Berlinetta</option>\n<option value=\"laferrari\">La Ferrari</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "fiat":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"punto\">Punto</option>\n<option value=\"panda\">Panda</option>\n<option value=\"500\">500</option>\n<option value=\"albea\">Albea</option>\n<option value=\"bravo\">Bravo</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "lamborghini":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"miura\">Miura</option>\n<option value=\"espada\">Espada</option>\n<option value=\"jarama\">Jarama</option>\n<option value=\"countach\">Countach</option>\n<option value=\"silhouette\">Silhouette</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "maserati":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"quattroporte\">Quattroporte</option>\n<option value=\"ghibli\">Ghibli</option>\n<option value=\"granturismo\">Gran Turismo</option>\n<option value=\"grancabrio\">Gran Cabrio</option>\n<option value=\"levante\">Levante</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "audi":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"a1\">A1</option>\n<option value=\"a8\">A8</option>\n<option value=\"s3\">S3</option>\n<option value=\"q5\">Q5</option>\n<option value=\"ttrs\">TT RS</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "bmw":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"1series\">1 Series</option>\n<option value=\"3series\">3series</option>\n<option value=\"5series\">5 Series</option>\n<option value=\"i3\">i3</option>\n<option value=\"x3\">X3</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "goliath":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"gp700\">GP 700</option>\n<option value=\"gp900\">GP 900</option>\n<option value=\"dreirad\">Dreirad</option>\n<option value=\"gv800\">GV 800</option>\n<option value=\"express\">Express</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "porche":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"911\">911</option>\n<option value=\"boxter\">Boxter</option>\n<option value=\"carrera\">Carrera</option>\n<option value=\"cayenne\">Cayenne</option>\n<option value=\"macan\">Macan</option>\n";
                    break;
            case "volkswagen":
                    $returnValue = "<option value=\"newbeetle\">New Beetle</option>\n<option value=\"jetta\">Jetta</option>\n<option value=\"passat\">Passat</option>\n<option value=\"touareg\">Touareg</option>\n<option value=\"phaeton\">Phaeton</option>\n";
                    break;
            default:
                    $returnValue = "<option selected disabled>Choose make</option>\n";
    }

    error_log("Here is the list of models: " . $returnValue);
    echo $returnValue;
?>
```

Like I said, this works fantastically in Firefox, but not at all in IE. Any input (positive or negative) would be greatly appreciated. Also, I cannot use jQuery.

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

EDIT

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =

As a follow-up to this post, I applied the suggested technique of using json_encode on the PHP side and JSON.parse on the JavaScript side. This does, indeed, work using Internet Explorer; however, with database calls that return thousands of hits, it really slows down the browser ... A LOT! Here is what I am working with now, using a list of FEMA disasters I got from the data.gov website:

JavaScript:

```
function filtered(){
    var tableBody = document.getElementById('tableToPopulate');
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete"){
        var listOfDisasters = xmlHttp.responseText;
        var j = 0;
        for(var i=0; i<JSON.parse(listOfDisasters).length; i++){
            var disaster = JSON.parse(listOfDisasters)[i];
            var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
            for(var index in disaster){
                var newCell = document.createElement("td");
                var node = document.createTextNode(disaster[index]);
                newCell.appendChild(node);
                newRow.appendChild(newCell);
            }
            tableBody.appendChild(newRow);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

The Back-End PHP:

```
<?php
        $filter = (isset($_GET['filter']) && $_GET['filter'] != '') ? strip_tags($_GET['filter']) : null;
        $filterCriteria = (isset($_GET['filterCriteria']) && $_GET['filterCriteria'] != '') ? strip_tags($_GET['filterCriteria']) : null;
        $returnValue = null;
        $arrayOfResults = array();

        $query = "select fd.ID,fd.DisasterNumber,fd.DeclarationDate,i.IncidentType,s.State,fd.County,fd.ApplicantName,fd.EducationApplicant,fd.NumberOfProjects,fd.FederalShareObligated from DISASTERS fd join INCIDENTTYPE i on i.ID = fd.IncidentTypeID join STATE s on s.ID = fd.StateID where " . $filter . " like '%" . $filterCriteria . "%' order by State,County,IncidentType";
        error_log("Filter Query: " . $query);
        if($result = $dbConnection->query($query)){
                while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                        $tmpArray = array();
                        $tmpArray['DisasterNumber'] = $row->DisasterNumber;
                        $tmpArray['DeclarationDate'] = $row->DeclarationDate;
                        $tmpArray['IncidentType'] = $row->IncidentType;
                        $tmpArray['State'] = $row->State;
                        $tmpArray['County'] = $row->County;
                        $tmpArray['ApplicantName'] = $row->ApplicantName;
                        $tmpArray['EducationApplicant'] = $row->EducationApplicant;
                        $tmpArray['NumberOfProjects'] = $row->NumberOfProjects;
                        $tmpArray['FederalShareObligated'] = $row->FederalShareObligated;
                        array_push($arrayOfResults, $tmpArray);
                }
                $result->close();
        }

        $returnValue = json_encode($arrayOfResults);

        error_log($returnValue);
        echo $returnValue;
?>
```

The data file I got from data.gov is over 131K lines, so some of the database queries can return a few thousand lines. I know this is a lot, but the innerHTML method does work faster than does the DOM method. Maybe there is a more efficient way to do this. If so, I would appreciate any input on the matter.

Comment: Which version of _IE_ ? Do you get any error messages in the _console_ ?

Comment: `console.log` doesn't work in IE unless the console is open. Therefore only use `console.log` when you are testing.

Comment: IE 8 ... no errors, it just doesn't work. It looks like it almost works, in that I get, what looks like, and empty drop-down list.

Comment: Always use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to properly encode query string parameters (variable names as well as values). (Not that it matters in this case, but you might eventually try to send characters that should be encoded.) You should also check `xmlHttp.status`, it could be something else than 200. What does `console.log(selectListOptions)` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.innerHTML` is non-standard. Most browsers support it but as you've found out some better than others. I think especially in the case of forms you can see some strange behaviour.

The *proper* way is to use the DOM API:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.setAttribute("value", value);
selectList.appendChild(option);
```

There are still some minor caveats but IE8 and up should be fine.

Comment: So, how would I do this if my PHP function sent back multiple lines? Delimit the end of each one, use the JavaScript "split" method, and loop through each one?

Comment: IE was the first browser to support `.innerHTML`. I also use it a lot and I don't get any errors with it whatsoever.

Comment: @Brian You could also send back JSON-formatted text and build the menu in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @MarcelKorpel. JSON is excellent for this. Build your options array in PHP and `echo json_encode($options)`. Then in JavaScript you can `JSON.parse(responseText)` and you'll have your array.

Comment: @Brian Note that `JSON.parse` is only supported by IE>=8. For anything below that, use `json2.js` or `json_sans_eval` from http://json.org.

Comment: Ok, so I build up a multi-dimentional array in PHP, use the json_encode method to "wrap it up", then use json.parse on the JavaScript side to "unwrap" it, then use the DOM API to build the list?

Comment: Yes, just go ahead and try it, if you're stuck make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(selectListOptions);
```

probably is not supporting in IE, try to comment this line